# Binanace get Order Book in C# .Net Core

Tags: c#, websocket, real-time, binance, orderbook

i'm part of a MarketMaker team and currently need to get crypto Market Data from Binance. Here are the requirements...

- get public market data, so dont have api keys
- get order book market depth, at least last 1000 bid/ask prices.
- use websocket, not restful http calls

How to do this? Which .NET library i can use that provides realtime (websockets)
to can keep giving me market data of order book in last 1000 bids/asks

I cant seem to find the library needed, they either need an API key or dont provide up to 1000 bid/ask, i can only get up to 20 depth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it through BinanceDotNet api

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).